# Passing Binding to child scripts

Tags: groovy

How to pass the groovy binding to the child scripts, for example from Groovy script A i have to pass the binding Groovy Script B ?

```
Level1.groovy    
new Level2().run()

level2.groovy
new Level3().run()

level3.groovy
if (binding) {

}
```

if i set some binding in level1.groovy how can i access in level3.groovy

Comment: Do you have example code that isn't working?

Comment: @tim_yates if i set some binding in level1.groovy how can i access in level3.groovy

Comment: It's hard to say with such a vague example (I would need to make a lot of assumptions to come up with something to test), but why not do it the way Groovy intended with something like the [GroovyScriptEngine](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.html#run%28java.lang.String,%20groovy.lang.Binding%29) for running each script?  Without some exact and accurate steps that I can follow to reproduce your problem, there's not much else I can suggest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Level1.groovy    
new Level2(binding).run()

level2.groovy
new Level3().run()

level3.groovy
if (binding) {

}
```